# Implicit conversion using as from JsLookupResult to List[Map[String, JsValue]] error

Tags: json, scala, maven, typesafe, jsvalue

I have this `scala` code which parses `json` and gets `notifiers` object from `jsonValue`.

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val json = 
      """{
         "notifiers":[
            {
               "type":"url",
               "attributes":{
                  "msg":"Hello world!"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filters":[],
         "position":{}
      }"""
    val jsonValue: JsValue = Json.parse(json)
    (jsonValue \ "notifiers").as[List[Map[String, JsValue]]]
  }
}
```

Why I am getting this error on last line?

> Multiple markers at this line:
>     - Line breakpoint:App [line: 25] - App
>     - Implicit conversion found: jsonValue ⇒ jsValueToJsLookup(jsonValue): play.api.libs.json.JsLookup
>     - bad symbolic reference. A signature in DefaultReads.class refers to term time in package java which is not available. It may be completely
>   missing from the       current classpath, or the version on the classpath
>   might be incompatible with the version used when compiling
>   DefaultReads.class.

Using Scala 2.10.6 and this project is a maven module with `com.typesafe.play` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-json_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

*Ps. I have done the same in some other program where I'm using this `.as` `(def as[T](implicit fjs: Reads[T]): T`) to type convert from `JsLookupResult` into `List[Map[String, JsValue]]` with no errors.*

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JDK 8 or a previous version of Play. Play 2.4 only supports JDK 8 (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) - the error you're getting is about being unable to find member `time` in package `java`, which has been introduced since JDK 8.